# tablesorter is not a function rails 6 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, tablesorter

I am trying to add tablesorter to my tables but I end up with the following error on the browser console.
`Uncaught TypeError: n(...).tablesorter is not a function`
Here is my `application.js`:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
require('jquery')
import "channels"
import "cocoon";
import "chartkick/chart.js"
import tablesorter from 'tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter'
Rails.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
import '../stylesheets/application'
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"

require("stylesheets/application")

$(function () {
    $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
    showProcessing: true,
    // initialize zebra and filter widgets
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: false, filter: false },
      13: { sorter: true, filter: true }
    }
  });
})
```

I have added the gem in the Gemfile `jquery-tablesorter`. I have also done `yarn add jquery` and `yarn add tablesorter` but I am still stuck.

Note: `jquery-tablesorter` is the only gem related to jquery that I have in my Gemfile.

Comment: Are you sure that a class "tablesorter" is in the html?
-- $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({ --
because it throws here if i read the error correctly that $('.tablesorter') is null / undefined

Comment: Yeah. I mean the class is not on every page so I get your point. Although, even if the class is there, it results in this: ```Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function```. So not much of a change i guess

Comment: In the usage example on [EXAMPLE](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) they use only id´s if you could try to make an id and test if its still not working

Comment: no, still the same

Comment: does the table sorter get loaded first or the jquery library first? ( like in the answer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where `$` is being loaded here. Tablesorter doesn't have access to it to define `tablesorter` function. You need to explicitly import it.

```js
import jQuery from "jquery";
import "tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

or

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
require("tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter");
```

Comment: Nope, the ```$``` gets loaded correctly but still it is not able to identify ```tablesorter``` as a function.``` jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).tablesorter is not a function ./app/javascript/packs/application.js/</<@http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-```

Comment: hmm, how do you check that it gets loaded correctly?

Comment: the $(.tablesorter) captures the table on the page while using the browser console